# Alternative to hidden text fieds in ruby on rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I have read several articles on security of hidden fields in the form.And I am worried about it.Is there any alternate techniques so that i can secure my ruby on rails application by removing hidden fields?

Comment: Can you specify for which purpose you want to use hidden field?

Comment: i want to pass user id and another one for checking from where the request came?!

Comment: You should use hidden fields, see link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Store this data in the session, and use a session store that persists on the server, such as an activerecord session.

Comment: That helped me!But Is it Secure?

Comment: my application runs without login so may session will not work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For you case, it's better to use hidden fields. See this post http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=29914

Comment: But It will decrease my security that's why i have posted this question @Ramiz.

Comment: session store is the other option but i don't think that it's a better idea to use session just store user_id.